# dev sda8 clean + mongodb and groovy problem

Tags: boot, storage

I get this message after my laptop boots.

```
/dev/sda8: clean, 604059/10049729 files, 72754401/75379456 blocks
```

I entered a TTY and ran `sudo apt-get update`and I got this :

[image]

[image]

I think it's a problem with mongo. What can I do to fix it?

---

I ran `df -h` and got this:

[image]

It looks like sda8 is full, so I ran `df -h` and got the following:

```
/dev/sda8 283G 273G    0  100% /
```

I don't see how I could have used up 273 G

Comment: The "apt update" say's no space left on device ... is your disk full ? Please update the question with the output of `df -h`

Comment: As for the `/dev/sda8: clean` message, that's the output from a routine check of your file system(s) that happens on every boot. You normally don't see it or ignore it.

Comment: Just updated, looks like my disk is full indeed

Comment: I’m sorry I can’t post the text because my computer will not boot. I’m stuck with a black terminal and I cannot copy the text.

Comment: Also what do you mean by upgrade the answer? You mean edit?